# Due Date of a task?

Tags: list, wss-3.0

I have a list on "Research" ..Since many people are engaged in research work, there is continuous change of due date and 'Responsibility' field.
I want a way whereby, Every time the value in Responsibility field changes the due date is archived/appended and the current value in the field becomes blank.

Is this possible?

Awaiting your replies.

thx!!

-saumil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a custom list to store the history of changes to a piece of research (which I assume is a Task List).

You could have a workflow that fires when an item is changed, whichs creates a row in your archive list, storing the ID of the task in question, who it was assigned to, and who it is now assigned to (showing before and after), and perhaps also storing similar changes to due date.

So, your custom list would have the columns:

TaskID, OldAssignedTo, NewAssignedTo, OldDueDate, NewDueDate

Your workflow fires on changing an item in your Research list, and creates a row in this list.

You can easily do this within SharePoint Designer 2007 and within WSS3.

Cheers!

Comment: Awesome! Thx James!